# MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource - Can not insert to mysql db using jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have to use a custom  jdbc connection pooling library to connect to mysql db.

The problem is my that inserts are not persisted in db... To narrow down the issue, I extracted the portion of the library code inserting into db and have some strange findings:

```
MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ds1 = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
ds1.setUser("usr");
ds1.setPassword("pwd");
ds1.setServerName("server");
ds1.setPort(port);
ds1.setDatabaseName("dbname");
ds1.setUseSSL(false);
ds1.setAllowPublicKeyRetrieval(true);


Connection conn = ds1.getPooledConnection("usr", "pwd").getConnection();

logger.info("connection " + conn.toString());

PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {

    String query = "INSERT INTO ...";
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    int timeout = 10;
    ps.setQueryTimeout(timeout);

    logger.info("timeout: " + timeout);
    logger.info("Starting query execution for query: " + query);
    long qeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ps.setString(1, "...");

    ps.executeUpdate();

    long qeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logger.info("Query execution completed in " + (qeEnd - qeStart) + "msec.");
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("ERROR OCCURED", e);
    System.err.println("ERROR OCCURED");
    e.printStackTrace();

} finally {
    closeResultSet(rs);
    closeStatement(ps);
    closeConnection(conn);
}
```

The above code does NOT work when I connect to a remote mysql db  with version: 8.0.11-commercial . By not working I mean there is no error, the insert is simply lost...

When I execute the same code against my local mysql db with version : 8.0.11 hosted on windows machine, it is working...

If I change connection getting code from

```
Connection conn = ds1.getPooledConnection("usr", "pwd").getConnection();
```

to:

```
Connection conn = ds1.getConnection();
```

it also starts to work against remote mysql db  with version: 8.0.11-commercial...

The autocommit mode of the underlying connection is already true...

I tried to implement a custom log4j logger with the hope of seeing some trace but that did not help either:

```
ds1.setLogger("com.ibtech.mysqlproblem.Log4jLogger");
```

My custom connection pooling library uses pooled connection so I need to get the above code working. In the client I am using mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Why not to switch to a well-tested connection pool instead of maintaining your own custom implementation? As long as the code is using sane abstraction e.g. `java.sql.DataSource` there should be no impact on the application logic.

Comment: Hi Karol that is not possible because of deployment, management decisons etc.. But the above code demonstrates problem without any connection pool...I am executing it in an isolated main class and seeing the same error. Do you have any recommendation for the actual problem?

Comment: The only recommendation I can give you is to switch to [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). It's tricky to write a pool that is [correct and handles weird behaviours](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Pool-Analysis).

Comment: As the above code demonstrates my current problem is not related with pool...........

Comment: You seem to think that a `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` is a connection pool, it is **NOT**. A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is intended as a factory for connections held in a connection pool. In other words, it is **used by** a connection pool. You shouldn't use it directly in your code. Anyway, have you tried using `conn.commit()`?

Comment: Hi Mark, I know the difference.. As you say MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource is used by my custom pool. I wrote the above code just to show my problem... (I.e in production code I will not instantiate MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource ). As for the commit I already mentioned it. Connections from pool are served with autoCommit set to true. If I manually set it to false and then commit it works but that is not what I want. I need autocommit behavior. I am trying to change the db from oracle to mysql. I have no problem in oracle..

Comment: I do not know what it does and what is used for, but setting paranoid property seems to solve my issue (  ds1.setParanoid(true); for the above code sample) at least for single insert. Hope that it also works for batch inserts...

Answer (score 0):

It seems totally unrelated but setting paranoid property to true seemed to solve my problem...

**----------------Edit : Root cause understood---------------------------------------**

Problem occurs when global autocommit value is 0 in the server. Issuing change user command, clears session data and autocommit setting is lost.

A workaround solution is to set autocommit flag once again once the connection is acquired...

Thanks to Filipe for analyzing the problem..

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,666702,666986#msg-666986

**----------------Edit : Bug created--------------------------------------**

It turned out that it is a bug in the JDBC driver. A bug has been filed...

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91351